# Developing an Eclipse Content Assist plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, content-assist

I am trying to extend the default behaviour of content assist for XML files in Eclipse (Helios or lower). I need to add some predefined list items in an XML file when a user types a particular string and presses `Ctrl+Space`. 
I tried to search over the internet and got some basic knowledge from [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_contentassist.htm) and from [this blog](http://outofmemoryblog.blogspot.in/2012/03/developing-content-assistant-for.html). 
 However, being a newbie in writing plugins, I'm unable to figure out some points, like

- What should be the plugin template?
- or where will the implementing class reside?

I am unable to find any tutorial which can explain it in a better way. Any suggestions in terms of useful links/tutorials would be a great help.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help you link to is for developing content assist in a new editor. If what you want is to add to the existing Eclipse WST XML editor then you have to use the `org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.completionProposal` extension point defined by WST to add content proposals. There is an example [here](http://kofler.nonblocking.at/2013/07/extending-the-content-assist-capabilities-of-the-eclipse-xml-editor/)

Comment: Link for the example is broken